# ssis Package validation error ole db source failed

Tags: sql, ssis-2012

I am getting the following error when I try and run my package.  I am new to ssis.  Any suggestions.  Tahnks

===================================

Package Validation Error (Package Validation Error)

===================================

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32 launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA shows up when the underlying data behind one of the tasks changes. The fastest solution will probably be to just delete and re-create each element which is throwing an error.

Answer (score 5):

How about disabling validation checks?

Like if you right click on source or destination component and select properties then you will have the property named validateExternalMetadata put that as false and try.

This Solution is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This normally occurs if there has been a change to your schema, not to stress, just double click on your input and output and it should resolve itself

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your connection is valid. If you are using dynamic connections, then try to set the option "delay validation" = true on the package or dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

In my case destination table structure was not matching with matadata in OLEDB component. I added the missing column which i forgot to add and after that it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit (check to extract your own conclusions: [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssis-case-sensitivity-may-expose-issues-with-change-deployment) and [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22fb4b15-2b2b-4408-96a8-bdc8897c17cf/failed-validation-and-returned-validation-status-quotvsneedsnewmetadataquot?forum=sqlintegrationservices)), I think I've found a nice **workaround** for when the problem with the metadata comes from a `Ole DB` object, but **only for a very specific case**.

The thing is that when you change your columns *names* / remove columns / add columns, you can't do anything but update the metadata.

However, if you use a `SQL query` to retrieve the data from the object, *in the case* that you don't need to update the query itself, **you won't need to update the metadata if the query still can ask for what it wants**. Basically, if the query is still valid.

I've tried it within my own ETL, and changed an `Ole DB` object which was reading the data from an `Excel` file, targeting one `sheet` and then I had all the columns selected in the tab.

Changing it for an `SQL query` to retrieve the full sheet like:

```
SELECT * FROM ['Sheet_Name$']
```

Solved completely the case for me, even introducing files with different metadata in headers.

Comment: Beware that SELECT * opens the door to all kinds of problems.